# How to display an existing Facelets page in a <p:dialog>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

Is it possible to display a previously created Facelets page completely in a `<p:dialog>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place `<ui:include src="myPage.xhtml" />` inside your `<p:dialog`

like this

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dlg" >  
    <ui:include src="myPage.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```